# How to get NHibernate ISession to cache entity not retrieved by primary key

Tags: nhibernate, caching, isession

My 'user' entity is almost always retrieved by username, rather than by its integer surrogate key. Because the username is not the primary key, this means that the ISession won't cache it and repeatedly hits the database to get the same data.

Is there any way at all I can configure NHibernate to get the ISession to cache users retrieved by username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer is in fact no. Yes, if you're using the second level cache, no if you are using the Session cache.

Comment: The answer to the question is no, but the problem can be solved using Sergi Papaseit's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272094/architecture-problem-use-of-dependency-injection-resulting-in-rubbish-api

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use NHibernate's natural-id element to accomplish this. See http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/23/nhibernate-ltnatural-idgt.aspx, the example is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: In fact, the natural-id element by itself is not enough; you'll have to enable 2nd level caching.

Comment: This is what I feared. I don't want to use the second level cache. I use Session-Per-Request, and I don't want cached items to last any longer than that. I think the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 1):

The "session cache" is actually not a cache, but an entity map.

My suggestion is that you enable the 2nd level cache for queries using a custom provider that stores items in the HttpContext.

Comment: In what sense is it not a cache? It stores entities loaded from the database and removes the need for them to be loaded from the database subsequently. That's a cache where I'm from! Thank you for your suggestion about an HttpContext-based cache provider.